# isnot escaping <script> enough to avoid XSS?

Tags: javascript

So, all I have read is XSS might happen:

a) we get `query` parameter from url and places it into the DOM. if attacker tries to put some kind of `<script>` tag and sends this to other people as links, as soon as they go to that link, Here you go. XSS happened.

b) If hacker puts some kind of `<script>` into the form and submits it and this gets stored on a server's Database. if some other people enter the website which fetches data from that db and particulary, hacker's data, it's gonna execute and here you go. XSS happened.

I've read some articles about how to prevent this and they talk too much, too many things.

**I wonder if we do the following:** whenever user tries to type something in my website's input, I will escape only `<script>` tags and not any other tags, since I also want user to send some formatted code such as `<strong>good</strong>` via input.

So, can you tell me other examples other than only escaping `<script>` tags, and  XSS still might happen?

Comment: `<img src=x.x onerror="alert('oh noes')">`. you also have forms, meta redirects, onmouseover, etc...

Comment: You might be interested in reading this article : https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html

Comment: @dandavis so any html tag can produce XSS, right?

Comment: i don't know about "any", but a lot of them can. use markdown or bbcode to allow richer user input.